# Passing Colour from program to vertex shader

Tags: opengl, vertex-buffer-object

New to opengl! I am having issues with passing colours from the program to vertex shader.

I am creating a grid where I want to control the color of each cell.Thus I am generating each cell and having two vbo's, one for the vertices, and another for the colour. I want my grid to look like this:

[image: Ideal]

But I end up with:

[image: Reality]

I have confirmed if I generate the colour data in the vertex shader and then pass it to the fragment, I get the first case. It is only when I grab the colour data from the program that I get the second case.

Code for creating each vbo(written in go):

```
var vbo [2]uint32
gl.GenBuffers(2, &vbo[0])
gl.BindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0])
gl.BufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 4*len(points), gl.Ptr(points), gl.STATIC_DRAW)
gl.BindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[1])
gl.BufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 4*3, gl.Ptr([]float32{0.5,0.5,0.0}), gl.STATIC_DRAW)
var vao uint32
gl.GenVertexArrays(1, &vao)
gl.BindVertexArray(vao)
gl.EnableVertexAttribArray(0)
gl.BindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0])
gl.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, nil)

gl.EnableVertexAttribArray(1)
gl.BindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[1])
gl.VertexAttribPointer(1, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, nil)
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 410
/*layout (location=0) */in vec3 vp;
/*layout (location=1)*/ in vec3 colour;
/*layout (location=2)*/  out vec3 outcolour;
void main(){
    gl_Position = vec4(vp,1.0);
    //outcolour = vec3(0.5,0.5,0.0);
    outcolour = vec3(colour);
}
```

Fragment Shader

```
#version 410
in vec3 outcolour;
out vec4 frag_colour;
void main(){
    frag_colour = vec4(outcolour,1.0);
}
```

Comment: `/*layout (location=1)*/` Why did you comment out important declarations like that?

Comment: I had a bug where I was unable to obtain attribute indices that I resolved. The indices that I declared (and commented out) just so happened to be the same ones that the compiler chose. Already changed it back to query the attribute index based on the name!

Comment: Why query the attribute index when you can just *specify it* in the shader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what language that is, but I'm going to hazard a guess that the arrays `points` and `gl.Ptr([]float32{0.5,0.5,0.0})` are *not* the same size. If you intend to provide per-vertex colors, then you must provide one color for *every vertex*. If you want to provide a single color that all vertices share, then that would be a `uniform`, not a vertex shader `in`put.

Also, commenting out your `layout` declarations isn't helping. Though if you are going to declare a `location` for the VS output variable, then the matching FS input needs to have the same `location` declared.

Comment: Thank you! Updating it to have one color per vertex worked!

Comment: If I may ask for furthur optimization and advice, Currently in order to generate those quadrilateral cells, I am using 8 vertices for each cell. This then means each time I change the colour of a cell, I send 3*4*8 bytes each time. I changed it to send a third of the data by creating the colour in the shader itself, and using an int to determine which colour to use. Is there a more efficient method than the one I just described?

Comment: Since the original question was about getting the code to work correctly, you could post a separate question about efficiency.

Comment: `not the same size` solved my problem.